# React proxy issue with the API server

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, proxy

I am a newbie with the react project deployment. The API server is the Laravel project and it's hosted on the Siteground.

I am sure the APIs works by Postman. And the react project runs on `localhost:3000`. In order to fetch some data with API, I have added the `proxy: "http://api server domain"` into the `package.json`.

It always says "Not allowed method" when I am going to fetch the data.

So I have hosted the API server on the localhost. In this case, I have added the `proxy: "http://localhost:8000` into the package.json, it works perfectly.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like you're having a **CORS** (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem.

According to MDN, CORS is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own.

An example of a cross-origin request: the front-end JavaScript code served from https://domain-a.com uses XMLHttpRequest to make a request for https://domain-b.com/data.json.

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

More technical details [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

**Solving:**

You need to enable CORS on your API service.

If you don't have access to configure Apache, you can still send the header from a PHP script. It's a case of adding the following to your PHP scripts:

```
 <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

The following link shows how to: [How to enable CORS on PHP](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)

Since you're using Laravel, using a middleware may be a good way to solve your CORS situation.

[CORS Middleware for Laravel](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) should help you.